# How to customize django admin

Tags: django, admin

This code is working properly.But i want some form to write the subject and message in order to reply instead of defining subject message in the reply function. How can i add reply form for the reply acction in django admin page

> admin.py

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['full_name','email','comment','time']
list_filter = ['time']
search_fields = ['name','comment']
readonly_fields = ['full_name','email','comment','time']
ordering = ['time']
actions = ['reply']

def reply(self,request,queryset):
    for reciever in queryset:
        send_mail('subject','message',settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[reciever.email],fail_silently=False)
        messages.success(request,'Your message has been replied successfully.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows: Create a custom admin template. Copy the standard template from the django installation into the directory yourproject/templates/admin/youapp/yourmodel/change_list.html
Replace the names yourproject etc. with your names.

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    change_list_template = 'admin/yourapp/yourmodel/change_list.html'
```

Then you modify this template within the form element (modifications are shown between the comment lines - there is just two lines inserted):

```
      {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}

        <!--Inserted code starts here-->

        <input type="message" name="mail_subject">
        <textarea type="message" name="mail_message"><textarea>

        <!--End of inserted code-->

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

And then you can access the values of those two inputs in your action-method.

```
def send_mail(self, request, queryset):
    form_data = request.POST.dict()
    subject= form_data["mail_subject"]
    message = form_data["mail_message"]
    ... and then send your emails
```

Comment: Thakns for your reply.can you please write what we have to extend and load  in change_list.html

Comment: What TEAdmin is ??

Comment: I edited the answer - I found a much simpler solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.how can i copy standard template from the django installation.In change_list.html  page there is only form.other dissapered.I Want change_list.html under my reply action only not in the whole contact page

Comment: the template is in "django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/". Copy the change_list.html from there into your project at yourproject/templates/admin/yourapp/yourmodel. Maybe also rename it (eg. to change_list_mod.html) to make sure you get an error if django does not find it - then you also need to change the line: change_list_template = 'admin/yourapp/yourmodel/change_list_mod.html'

Comment: sir i did't find this directory django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/ anywhere .I am very new to django  so I am sorry for my stupid questions.Thank you for your help

Comment: The django folder has to be somewhere, you just need to find the path. Is it in your python/Lib/site-packages folder?

Comment: You should also mark this question as answered then.